# Canvas vs SVG for graph-like diagrams?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, html5-canvas

I want to create web app wich will be able to build mind maps.
Backend isn't problem for me but frontend is: i'm not sure which technology to use.

App should build unlimited graphs where each node should be editable and contain text.

Answer (score 2):

SVG! Infinitely zoomable, well supported in modern browsers (incl. Firefox 4 and up) and works well with text.

Comment: also, it's well supported on mobile devices, and renders really well. vectors ftw!

Comment: use an SVG library though... writing SVG output directly is a huge pain!

Comment: It is not 100% true, SVG is not available on majority of Android devices. Version 2.2 and earlier. So Canvas is unfortunately better choice at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I would also tell you to check http://raphaeljs.com/ makes your life easier.

When it comes to animation it is tempting to go along HTML5 canvas but if your need is complex animations or require more control and quality, SVG is the way to go.

Apart from quality the other cons in HTML5 canvas are behind the scenes it is a pixel manipulation, and you would not get DOM for each object meaning you cannot call them by ID or manipulate them singularly. Every small change is redraw.

SVG on the other hand gives DOM level of control and supported by webkits

Answer (score 0):

I'd say canvas if I had to choose between the two.

There's a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568136/svg-vs-canvas-where-is-the-web-world-going-towards) which will give you a more comprehensive answer, but it's got great support, gaining momentum as part of html5 and also (if it makes a difference) has good mobile support.

However I'd also say that they're quite different and there's nothing to stop you using both of them as they can certainly work well together.